# cfChart use Local Style XML

Tags: xml, coldfusion, cfchart

I'm 99% sure this is possible, having seen it in a forum some time ago. I want to use a XML style file for CfChart that is in the same folder as the CFM file that's making the chart.

I know that in `<cfchart format="png" style="XXX">` the XXX will look in my charting/style folder of my coldfusion root folder. But I want to override that and look in the directory I'm running my CFM from.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a dirty way to do it, is just read the XML and use it as a variable.... something like this:

```
 <cfset strPath = GetDirectoryFromPath( GetCurrentTemplatePath()) />


<cffile action="read" file="#strPath#/nutrientGraph.xml" variable="graphStyle">
```

Comment: No need to read it into a string. As mentioned in the other thread, just use a relative file path. For example, `<cfchart style="./yourStyle.xml">`